# Dividing polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When dividing variables, does each term in the numerator have to have a variable for it to be divided? For example if the problem is 
$$\frac{9x+8x^2+1}{x}$$
can it be simplified to 
$$9+8x+1?$$ 
Or does there need to be an variable with the 1 in this case?

Comment: $\frac{9x+8x^2+1}{x} = \frac{9x}{x}+\frac{8x^2}{x}+\frac{1}{x} = 9+8x+\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the 1 cannot vanish. In your case, using the distributive law,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{9x + 8x^2 +1}{x} & = \frac{9x}{x} + \frac{8x^2}{x} + \frac{1}{x} \\
& = 9 + 8x + \frac{1}{x} \\
& \neq 9 + 8x + 1 \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Or an equivalent statement:  $9+8x$, Remainder 1

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check your work: what is $x\times(9+8x+1)$?

$$
x(9+8x+1) = 9x+8x²+x\ne 9x+8x²+1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at "1" is that it is $1\cdot x^0$.
In general, to get a non-negative power of $x$
when dividing $x^a$ by $x^b$,
you must have $b \le a$, and the result
will be $x^{a-b}$.

So, $\frac{1}{x} =\frac{1\cdot x^0}{x^1}
=1\cdot x^{0-1} = x^{-1}$.